# DropDownList Autopostback clears fields, reverts to default

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I have two drop down lists inside of two different fields in a detailsview, the first one determines the values of the second one.

When i select a value from the first ddl autopostback erases all data already in the detailsview and reverts the first dropdownlist back to the first selection.

Also when i select from the list (change the ddl selection more than once) it will throw a :

Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

```
------First DDL

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLLEAVECODE"
DataTextField="LEAVETYPE" DataValueField="LEAVECODE"
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
AppendDataBoundItems="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoPostBack="True"
SelectedValue='<%# BIND("REQLEAVECODE") %>' Width="80px">
<asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

-------Second DDL

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
DataTextField="REASON" DataValueField="REASON" 
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("leavetype") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>



---------page load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
}


--------DDL 1 selectedIndexChange
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList lvtype = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1"));
DropDownList lvreason = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList2"));
Label27.Text = lvtype.SelectedValue.ToString();

DetailsView1.Fields[4].Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Try this, you might have some fun:http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I went through that already but I seem to have problems because the ddl is in a details view, so i was unable to get cascading dropdownlist to work properly in my program

Answer (score 1):

If `Drop-down` is in `DetailsView` then please handle `ItemCommand event` of `DetailsView` instead of `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Hope this will help you

Comment: It is getting closer.  Now when I select from DDL1 it will keep the selected value on postback but it will not allow DDL2 to populate.

Comment: doing so resulted in this error :  Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup refers to `ID="DropDownList1"` and `ID="DropDownList2"`.

However, your event handler refers to `DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6")` and `DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6")`.  Could this be related to your problem?

Comment: sorry that was my transfer error, the dropdownlists are named 5 and 6 but I thought it would be confusing since 6 is the first one and 5 is the second so for forum purposes I changed it to 1 and 2 referring to the order.